# draw more than one thing on C# panel without bitmap

Tags: c#, graphics, panel, paint

I want to draw more than one shape on c# panel.
the problem is ; i am using **paint event handler** like this :

```
DrawPanel.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(callpaint);
```

callpaint is a function i use to draw things i want.

```
private void callpaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {//some code that use e.graphics//}
```

i want to trigger the callpaint handler when a button "draw" is clicked, i did it like this

```
 private void Draw(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //this is the button  click handler
        DrawPanel.Invalidate(); 

    }
```

the problem is when ever i call  DrawPanel.Invalidate();  the things i have drawn on the panel are deleted , **i want to draw new things and keep the old things** , **i have seen that bitmap can help but i can't use it**, is there any other way to solve the problem, thanks

Comment: You will need to __re-draw everything__ you want in/from the `Paint` event, ie collect all the data needed for this.. Also: Do not try to __cache__ the `e.Graphics` object!

Comment: There's a few ways to approach it.

You can - Take a screenshot of the image project it back onto the graphics object before rending other elements
OR
Keep a collection of all the items you need to render and re-render them all at the same time.

Comment: why i should not  cache e.graphics ?
do you mean that i shouldn't -like Zakk said- take a screenshot of the image ?
and if i want to do it with screen shot how to do that ? 
saving the data is very hard since i am drawing very complicated things

Comment: Taking a screenshot could work, *kind of*: as soon as you resize the control, you'd need to throw it away and draw everything from scratch.  And you shouldn't cache the Graphics object because it's only valid during the redraw and gets disposed by the calling code.  And the only reason you'd want to cache it rather than just using the one you're handed is if you're trying to draw outside of the Paint event handler, which is a very wrong thing to do.

Comment: _why i should not cache e.graphics_ this means:Do not cache the object. It doesn't contain any graphics, it is just a tool to draw onto a control or into a bitmap. - caching the drawn stuff may well be a good idea if the drawing is really expensive. but as you have drawn it already the data cannot really be too complicated to save. but redrawing thousands of shapes all the time may get a bit too slow..

Comment: thanks @adv12 so the only valid option is to some how save the data ?

Comment: How many drawxxx calss are we talking about? And: Do you need to change/und anything drawn? Is there interactivity? Why didn't you want to use a bitmap?

Comment: @Ali, as I said, that could *kind of* work, but only until you need to draw an area of the control not covered by the data you saved.  Typically people just redraw everything from scratch in every Paint event.  That's probably what you should do.

Comment: thank you @TaW  i would consider this option (saving the data). can i  save the graphics somehow or add to existing graphics ? or i should just save the parameters i need to redraw every thing ?
it is stupid thing i admit but i am not allowed to use bitmap because i have a stupid teacher who insists that i should not use bitmap it is kind of challenge

Comment: You need to save all necessary paramters so the Paint event can redraw when needed. One of the situations will be when drawing the data to a bitmap by `DrawToBitmap`. I usually [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+DrawAction) to craete a `drawAction` class to hold the parameters and to collect them in a `List<DrawAction>`.  __When and if__ they get too numerous you can pump the first n into a bitmap and clear the first n object but you won't need to for many draw calls..

Comment: I have a "drawAction" class, i think i will do it using  a list to save the parameters, thank you very much for fast response @TaW